# SELECT items that were recently change

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I want to select Item numbers that were recently changed based on timestamp, **THEN** use those item numbers to select/find ones that have bin=MASTER. Below what I tried:

```
SELECT  (SELECT cItemno FROM TB_BinLoc WHERE Updates > {ts '2020-12-17 05:00:00'} ) as x , cBin
FROM TB_BinLoc y
WHERE y.cItemno = x AND cBin = 'MASTER'
```

===============
This is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT cItemno, cWarehouse, cBin, nCounted, Updates FROM TB_BinLoc WHERE Updates > {ts '2020-12-17 05:00:00'}
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT y.cItemno, y.cWarehouse, y.cBin, y.nCounted, y.Updates
FROM TB_BinLoc y
JOIN TB_BinLoc x on y.cItemno = x.cItemno
Where y.cBin = 'MASTER' AND y.cWarehouse = 'MAIN'
AND x.Updates > {ts '2020-12-17 05:00:00'}
ORDER BY cBin ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join` as follows:

```
SELECT distinct x.cItemno as x , y.cBin
  FROM TB_BinLoc y
  Join TB_BinLoc x on y.cItemno = x.cItemno
 Where y.cBin = 'MASTER'
   And x.Updates > {ts '2020-12-17 05:00:00'}
```

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: If it worked for you then please accept the answer so that this question is marked as resolved

Answer (score -1):

It might be a good place to use window functions:

```
SELECT bl.*
FROM (SELECT bl.*, MAX(updates) OVER (PARTITION BY cItemNo) as max_update
      FROM TB_BinLoc bl
     ) bl
WHERE bl.cItemno = x AND blcBin = 'MASTER' AND
      bl.max_update > {ts '2020-12-17 05:00:00'}
```

Comment: @BachPhi . . . I have no idea what you mean by that.  That logic comes from the query in the question (the type was `update` rather than `updates`).

Comment: @BachPhi . . . Your comment doesn't make sense.  I will say that window functions are usually better performance wise than self-joins.

Comment: @BachPhi . . . Both those expressions are from **your** question.